# PCA on accounting data

Tags: pca

I'm working with a large dataset of accounting data along with business characterization data across 20 years. I would like to use PCA to reduce the variables' dimension (currently I have about 60 variables and 133k individuals) in order to eventually highlight interesting links between the variables and between business types.

I have several questions before diving into it:

- a lot of accounting variables are correlated by construction. Can it be an issue in terms of applicability or interpretability?
- the dataset gathers data from highly different types of business (this information is held by the business-characteristic kind of variables and I also have some knowledge on this). Therefore, could it hide "intra type of business variability"? And could it be an idea to run multiple "intra PCA" with only individuals belonging to the same category of business?
- should I account for the temporal character of the data?

Hoping it is not too vague and might be answered.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**First** of all, PCI is for continuous variables only. You might sometimes be able to change discrete variables into continuous ones, but that would be a topic for another question. I here presume that all your variables are continuous.

**Second**, a short introduction:
If you have 60 variables (or "features"), each individual becomes a point in a 60-dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^{60}$. So your data becomes a point cloud in $\mathbb{R}^{60}$. It is now often the case (actually, it happens most of the time), that this cloud is located along a much lower-dimensional subspace, e.g. it could be placed near a ten-dimensional linear subplane or a 12-dimensional sphere or ... In the case where your data cloud is located along a subplane, i.e. a linear subspace, you can use PCA to figure out that subplane.

**Third**, let's get to your questions:

Your **first** question: No, correlated data is not a problem. Actually, that is what PCA is all about, finding the correlations in your data. It can do this, as long as those correlations are linear.

Your **second** question: It is very well possible, that your data is clustered (e.g. by business), and that each cluster has "its own" subplane near which it is positioned. In this case, you would have to fit one PCA for each cluster/business.

Your **third** question: It depends. Sometimes, the structure of your data changes with time and that means that its subplane could change, too. If you suspect this, you should partition your data into "appropriate" time intervals and fit a PCA for each of those intervals.

As I said, PCA only works to find linear subspaces. This is a definite weakness of this method. On the other hand, linear relations between variables are much easier to understand and interpret. Nonlinear methods might fit your data better, but the results of those methods are often very difficult to draw conclusions from. Having said that, I think it never hurts to know about some of the nonlinear methods, so I will just mention [autoencoders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder) or some of the methods listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction).

This kind of analysis can become arbitrarily involved, but it is always a lot of fun to discover new insight into your data.
Happy PCA hunting.